# How to exclude an assembly from being packed into a PublishSingleFile app

Tags: .net-core, .net-5, .net-core-publishsinglefile

.NET Core and .NET 5 have the [single file executable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file) feature.

How can I exclude a managed assembly from being packed into that single file?

Example: I might want that `app.exe` includes `MyLib.A.dll` and `MyLib.B.dll`, but not `MyLib.Special.dll`. Instead, I might want that `MyLib.Special.dll` resides on disk next to `app.exe` and is loaded from there.

(Background: It could be that `MyLib.Special.dll` is licensed under the L-GPL, but `app.exe` is proprietary.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use ExcludeFromSingleFile inside of a ProjectReference element to prevent the assembly from being embedded, like so:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="MyLib.Special.csproj">
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assembly name `libxxx.dll` is confusing because of these reasons:

- Libraries naming with `lib` are under the naming convention in unix/linux systems. But `dll` is used in Windows only. There is either `foo.dll` or `libfoo.so`/`libfoo.dylib`.
- Libraries naming with `libfoo.so` or `foo.dll` means they are native assemblies, but native assemblies as dependencies are not handled automatically in MSBuild unless explicitly configured. A .NET managed assembly is named like `Foo.Bar.dll`.

Assuming that your libraries licenced under LGPL is a native assembly, the single file publish feature does not include it at all, so you may have to configure your project MSBuild file with a copy task to manually copy the assembly file from the project folder to the publish output folder, which must include this configuration to [prevent it from being bundled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file#exclude-files-from-being-embedded):

```
<ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
```

Comment: I agree that the assembly names I chose for the example might not be that great -> edited. However, thanks for the hint regarding `ExcludeFromSingleFile`. I was thinking of managed assemblies, which usually (??) are referenced using `<Reference>` or `<PackageReference>`. Do you know how to make `ExcludeFromSingleFile` work with `<Reference>` and `<PackageReference>`?

Comment: Consider copying the assembly file just like a native assembly and loading assembly dynamically. And if you need to access the types within your code, add a `Reference` with `HintPath`.

Comment: I can’t get this to work: .NET always uses the embedded assembly, never the one I load manually.

Comment: If you only reference the assembly by `HintPath`, I don't think MSBuild should embed it.

Comment: I did a `<Reference Include="..."><HintPath>...</HintPath></Reference>`, and in the code a `Assembly.Load`: It gets embedded and the assembly I load manually is not used. Maybe the answer is "you can't".